# Regex: Syntax pop on two linefeeds

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublime-syntax

I'm currently writing a Sublime syntax mode (YAML, for v3) for a language which has an unusual comment format.

*Documentation comments*:

- start with the symbol `#` as the first character in a LOC, and
- end with two newlines

A simple example is this:

```
# The following function returns
  the opposite of what you think it does.

code...
```

and a worst-case example:

```
#
  This is a comment,
this is still the same comment.
  This, too. These don't matter: # foobar ##

code...
```

My current approach is to use the stack.

Push:

```
- match: '#'
  scope: punctuation.definition.comment.mona
  push: doc_comment
```

Pop:

```
line_comment:
  - meta_scope: comment.line.mona
  - match: '\n\n'
    pop: true
```

That doesn't work though. I tried to fix this by using `s`, thinking that it would produce behavior like [this](https://regex101.com/r/V3IasN/1), but it produces a Sublime error (invalid option for capture group).

How can I match this comment format correctly with S3 YAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I'm a bit thick today. The answer was obvious, to match on an empty line:

```
 - match: '^$'
   pop: true
```